# Print Email Address in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, printing

I would like the email address to show when printing emails from Outlook 2010.  Is there any way to set this to default? Currently it only shows the persons first and last name.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change that. Internal addresses simply do not show as (in general) they are not needed as addressing the email by name would suffice since Exchange resolves them.

External addresses will show and do get printed. If an email gets forwarded, the external email address is also placed above the quoted text. Are you saying that this isn't the case for you?

If the person forwarding the message to you was internal for the original sender and they were using Exchange, then the original addresses wouldn't get quoted either of course.

If the order is generated by a form, you could opt to have the email address also be added to the message body.